# Recursive CTE on Dates

Tags: sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

I want to recursively loop though the temporary table by date1 field using following query in Sql server. I want that the @stardate and @enddate should auto increment up to the @stopcriteria initially starting from
'01/01/2011' to 12/31/2011' and then 
'01/01/2012' to 12/31/2012' and so on up to @stopCriteria and resultset should keep joining with union. I have written following query using cte but is not working.

```
   CREATE TABLE #tempbbs576 ( id int,  amount money, date1 date)   
insert into #tempbbs576(id,amount,date1)  values(1,1000,'1/1/2018')  
insert into #tempbbs576(id,amount,date1)  values(2,20010,'22/3/2019')  
insert into #tempbbs576(id,amount,date1)  values(3,40010,'1/1/2017')  
insert into #tempbbs576(id,amount,date1)  values(4,50010,'23/4/2018')  
insert into #tempbbs576(id,amount,date1)  values(5,60010,'1/1/2018')  
insert into #tempbbs576(id,amount,date1)  values(6,70010,'21/1/2018')   

    DECLARE @startDate DATE; 
    DECLARE @endDate DATE;   
    DECLARE @stopCriteria DATE;   
    SET @startDate='01/01/2011'; SET @endDate='12/31/2011'; SET @stopCriteria='01/01/2018';   

    ;WITH ctesequence 
         AS (SELECT 'Year' + Datename(year, Dateadd(year, 1, @startDate)) /*'2012'*/  
     AS FiscalYear, Count(DISTINCT id) AS Last2Years   
             FROM   [dbo].[#tempbbs576](nolock) WHERE  date1 BETWEEN @startDate AND    
     @endDate AND id IN (SELECT id FROM  [dbo].[#tempbbs576]  
                               WHERE  date1 < Dateadd(year, -1, @startDate) AND id    
     NOT IN (SELECT id FROM [dbo].[#tempbbs576]  WHERE  date1 BETWEEN  
     Dateadd(year,-1, @startDate) AND Dateadd( year, -1, @endDate ) ))   
             UNION   
             SELECT 'Year' + Datename(year, Dateadd(year, 1, @startDate)) /*'2012'*/  
     AS FiscalYear, Count(DISTINCT id)  AS Last2Years FROM ctesequence  WHERE  date1 <= @stopCriteria)  
    SELECT * FROM   ctesequence OPTION(maxrecursion 0)
```

Please let me know if it is possible through cte.

Thanks in Advance,
Amar